Qualtrics javascript - formatting function issue
I have been trying to work on javascript for a Qualtrics experiment.
Basically I am trying to generate a string of numbers and format a particular digit (targetDigit) in that string. I run this for 2 minutes, regenerating strings after an answer is subnmitted. This part of the code seems to work fine in the preview. The problem is that it does not do the formatting I indicate. Apart from the shared code, I have also tried using append and split but in both cases the formatting did not work (with my code). I hope I can get some help here. Thanks a lot!
I believe it is because the whole string is treated as 1 character instead of a collection of numbers. I also tried split function but for some reason it still did not work.
I can share the javascript code I have so far (applychanges() is the format function which I think is the issue). I have also tried running the last code segment separately  -
Code-
       Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
     {

           /* (irrelevant functions not included) */
           var button = document.getElementById('customSubmitButton');
           var input = document.getElementById('id_guess'); 
           var message = document.getElementById('message');

    
                // Generate the string 
    
               function generateDigitString(length) {
                let result = '';
                const digits = '0123456789';
                 for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                 result += digits.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * digits.length));
                  }
                 return result;
                 }

                let digitString = document.getElementById('mu_number').textContent;
                let targetDigit =  document.getElementById('target_digit').textContent;

                **function applyChanges() {
                 let styledText = '';
                 for (let i = 0; i < digitString.length; i++) {
                  console.log(targetDigit);
                    if (digitString[i] === targetDigit) {
                    console.log('done');
                     styledText += '<span style="font-size: 3em">${digitString[i]}</span>';
                     } else {
                     styledText += '<span style="font-size: 1em">${digitString[i]}</span>';
                     }
                   }

               document.getElementById('mu_number').innerHTML = styledText;

               applyChanges()
                }


          function styleTargetDigit(str, targetDigit) {
           const targetStr = targetDigit.toString();
            return str.replace(new RegExp(targetStr, 'g'), '<span style="font-weight:bold;">${targetStr}</span>');
           }

          let styledString = styleTargetDigit(digitString, targetDigit);
           document.getElementById('lambda_number').innerHTML = styledString;
           document.getElementById('target_digit').textContent = targetDigit;
           });

